# Handling NULL values in an SQL Query that uses SUM

Tags: sql, vba, excel

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to execute a query in VBA (Excel) containing a calculation using SUM e.g.

`Select SUM(field1) - SUM(field2) as 'newField' from y`.

If there are no null values or empty fields then the code works perfectly, however as soon as I have one null/empty value in either field1 or field2 then a blank is returned.

So if `SUM(field1) = 17 and SUM(field2) = null` I want to see the query return `17` instead of a blank value.

**The Code:**

```
Public Function GetRiskRecords(ByVal strPrgNo As String) As Variant

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Select [tblRiskMitigating$].RiskID, [tblRiskMitigating$].Program_No, [tblRiskMain$].RiskID, [tblRiskMain$].Program_No, [tblRiskMain$].Department, [tblRiskMain$].DateAdded, [tblRiskMain$].OwnerID, [tblRiskMain$].Description, " _
        & " [tblRiskMain$].RiskTo, [tblRiskMain$].Probability, " _
        & " Sum([tblRiskMain$].ScheduleImpact) - Sum([tblRiskMitigating$].ScheduleReduction) as 'NewScheduleImpact', " _
        & " Sum([tblRiskMain$].CostImpact) - Sum([tblRiskMitigating$].CostReduction) as 'NewCostImpact'" _
        & " From [tblRiskMain$]" _
        & " Left Join [tblRiskMitigating$] on [tblRiskMain$].RiskID = [tblRiskMitigating$].RiskID AND [tblRiskMain$].Program_No = [tblRiskMitigating$].Program_No" _
        & " Where [tblRiskMain$].Program_No = '" & strPrgNo & "'" _
        & " Group By [tblRiskMitigating$].RiskID, [tblRiskMitigating$].Program_No, [tblRiskMain$].RiskID, [tblRiskMain$].Program_No, [tblRiskMain$].Department, [tblRiskMain$].DateAdded, [tblRiskMain$].OwnerID, [tblRiskMain$].Description, " _
        & " [tblRiskMain$].RiskTo, [tblRiskMain$].Probability"

Call Open_Conn(strDb)
Call Open_RS(strSQL)

If rs.EOF Then
    Debug.Print ("Error: no records")
Else
    GetRiskRecords = rs.GetRows
End If

Call Close_RS
Call Close_Conn

End Function
```

**The Background:**

I have done a bit of digging around and have experimented with adding isnull and iif at the start but I haven't been able to get these to work at all (so I've omitted them from the question to reduce confusion from my original (main) question).

Comment: @pnuts Just trying to be polite, will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL/COALESCE`:

```
Select SUM(ISNULL(field1,0)) - SUM(ISNULL(field2,0)) as 'newField' 
from y;
```

or even combine to one `SUM`:

```
Select SUM(ISNULL(field1,0) - ISNULL(field2,0)) as 'newField' 
from y;
```

If `ISNULL/COALESCE` can be easily interchanged with `CASE WHEN` or `IIF`(`SQL Server 2012+`):

```
CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 0
     ELSE field1
END;

IIF(field1 IS NULL, 0, field1);
```

**EDIT:**

Above code is `SQL Server` oriented, for `EXCEL` you should use:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(field1 IS NULL, 0, field1) - IIF(field2 IS NULL, 0 field2)) 
FROM y
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Wrong number of arguments" when I try your suggestion. (I've changed nothing but added the syntax as recommended)

Comment: I have replaced line 3 of the above strSQL with `Sum(ISNULL([tblRiskMain$].ScheduleImpact,0) - ISNULL([tblRiskMitigating$].ScheduleReduction,0)) as 'NewScheduleImpact'`

Comment: @ppw Try with IIF version `SUM(IIF(field1 IS NULL, 0, field1) - IIF(field2 IS NULL, 0 field2))` or `SUM(IIF(ISNULL(field), 0, field1) - IIF(ISNULL(field2), 0 field2))`

Comment: The IIF version with IS NULL syntax worked like a charm, thank you very much for your help! Answer accepted.